# Can't get RQuantLib working with brew installed quantlib under osx 10.9.4

Tags: r, macos, boost, quantlib

I've been trying to install RQuantLib package via

```
install.packages("RQuantLib")
```

It keeps giving me the following errors

```
* installing *source* package ‘RQuantLib’ ...
** package ‘RQuantLib’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for R... yes
checking for quantlib-config... yes
checking for Boost development files... no
configure: error: Boost development files not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RQuantLib’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RQuantLib’
```

I've already done

```
brew install boost
brew install quantlib
```

and I've checked the sym links for both, which should be fine (done unlink/link for both).

---

SOLUTION :

Used the command below based on edd's answer, worked for me

```
install.packages("RQuantLib", configure.args="--with-boost-include=/usr/local/include/ --with-boost-lib=/usr/local/lib/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it either in a shell based on the `*.tar.gz` file using these

```
edd@max:~/git/rquantlib(master)$ ./configure --help|grep boost
  --with-boost-include=INCLUDE_PATH
  --with-boost-lib=LIB_PATH
edd@max:~/git/rquantlib(master)$
```

or look at the help for `install.packages()` where you can pass arguments to `configure` as well -- I find the first method easier.

In essence, it seems that we need to help configure find your Boost headers (and then probably also the library).