# Installing RQuantlib package on Mac 10.12.1

Tags: r, macos, clang, quantlib

I'm attempting to install the RQuantLib package from source, having already installed the requisite quantlib via `brew install quantlib` from the terminal.

After first failing to find Boost, but then [following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244606/cant-get-rquantlib-working-with-brew-installed-quantlib-under-osx-10-9-4), I attempted:

```
> install.packages("RQuantLib", configure.args="--with-boost-include=/usr/local/include/ --with-boost-lib=/usr/local/lib/")
```

However, this ultimately fails with the following warnings/ errors:

```
ld: 180 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RQuantLib.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RQuantLib’
```

I know little about clang, but it this truly a linker file issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please [this (long) thread at the repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/issues/80) as well as the resulting [wiki entry](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/wiki/RQuantLib).

As the (co-)author/maintainer I don't have an OS X machine, and for me things simply just work on Linux ...  Documentation for installation on other OSs has to be user-contributed, and luckily we have some.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (thanks to clues from Dirk, the package co-author, above) came from [this wiki entry he mentioned](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/issues/80), in particular requiring the editing of a .hpp file as detailed on [this github edit](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/pull/161/files), which will seemingly be fixed on its own once they push quantlib v 1.9.1